# operation.setContext errors with Apollo Boost

Tags: apollo-client

I've been using headers for authentication with Apollo Client. The following worked fine:

```
const middlewareAuthLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('auth-token');
    const authorizationHeader = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null;
    operation.setContext({
        headers: {
            authorization: authorizationHeader,
        },
    });
    return forward(operation);
});
```

Im switching over to Apollo Boost: https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/zero-config-graphql-state-management-27b1f1b3c2c3

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: 'MY-GRAPHCOOL-API',
    fetchOptions: {
        credentials: 'include',
    },
    request: async operation => {
        operation.setContext({
            headers: {
                authorization: 'sadfjadsfsd',
            },
        });
    },
    clientState: {
        defaults: {
            CurrentUserIsLoggedIn: {
                __typename: 'CurrentUserIsLoggedIn',
                value: false,
            },
        },
        resolvers: {
            Mutation: {
                CurrentUserIsLoggedIn: (_, args, { cache }) => {
                    const data = {
                        CurrentUserIsLoggedIn: {
                            __typename: 'CurrentUserIsLoggedIn',
                            value: args.value,
                        },
                    };
                    cache.writeData({ data });
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Now I get an error and my token isnt being added:

```
[Network error]: TypeError: operation.setContext is not a function
```

Comment: I receive the same error

Answer (score 2):

There's an open pull request on GitHub that addresses this issue: [[apollo-boost] pass operation prop to config.request](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/pull/3056)

Until it's merged, you can just apply the changes yourself in the `apollo-boost` package within your `node_modules` folder and run its build script with `yarn build`. Quick fix that worked for me.